# How do i write a program that finds the factorial of numbers 1-15

Tags: java

I have an assignment and I do not understand how to write a program that calculates factorials.
I've figured out how to do it with an user input but I am beginner and I do not know how to do it from 1-15.
I currently have this and I don't know how to apply it to a non-user input program

```
while (true) {
    int factorial,fact=1;
    System.out.println("Enter a number to execute a factorial function");
    factorial = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if (factorial <=0){
        System.out.println("Factorial is undefined");
    }
    else {
        for(int i =1;i<=factorial;i++){

            fact = fact * i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The factorial of your number is " + fact);
```

Comment: It always help to try something before asking a question here.

Comment: Calculating factorials is a very common programming assignment. You should be able t find all sorts of examples if you search. There's probably one in your book.

Comment: Again a factorial problem ? I start to feel old !

Comment: Hint: Use recursion.Try to write pseudo code first and then the actual java code. Thats how you will learn

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int fact(int num){
    if(num <= 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return num * fact(num-1);
}
```

Comment: Please do not feed the [help vampires](http://www.slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires).